# How to exclude nested <ul> and <li> on DOM selecting

Tags: jquery

I am having some trouble on targeting  correct li in my code. I have an unordered list like below

```
<li class="hassub"><span>Affected Areas</span>
            <ul class="sub1">
              <li><a href="#">Tacloban</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Guiuan</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Ormoc</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Roxas</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>
```

and a jquery as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hassub").click(function(){
    $(".sub1").slideToggle();
 });
});
```

Now my problem is even if user click on one of nested `<li>` on the second `<ul>` the `slideToggle()` function works! How can I limit the function to works ONLY on parent `<li>` class?

Comment: you would need to stop bubbling / propagation

Comment: You're using a specific class `hassub`, unless you have other li items with the same class, it won't toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check the class of the event `target` and `stopPropagation` in the event callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hassub").click(function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
    if ( $(ev.target).hasClass('hassub') || $(ev.target).parent('.hassub').length ) {
      // @Jack is right that you should keep the context
      $(".sub1", this).slideToggle();
    }
  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/93MBS/)

Comment: thanks Kalley but sometimes when I Click exactly on the text  <span>Affected Areas</span> and not the li area it is not working!

Answer (score 0):

Simple way if all you want is top level `li` to manage the click is to target the span in the top. Assumes span is set to fill the `li`

```
$('.hassub > span').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".sub1").slideToggle();
})
```

This way clicks on the subs are not being registered

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mdg72/)**</kbd>